# Get reference to a namespace where the function was called

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime, side-effects, dynamic-scope

Is there a general way in *Python 3* to get a reference to the module's namespace where the function was called? The problem arises from the fact that `global` in function references to the namespace where the function was  defined, but I want to obtain the reference to a namespace where it was called like in languages with dynamic scope.

In reality, I want to pollute the current namespace with predefined values during an interactive session, the similar to `from module import *` but with the call to `set_state()`.

```
from state import set_state
set_state()
```

The `from module import *` syntax is not enough because I have several configurations which are accessed like `set_state(3)`. I know that I can pass `locals()` as an argument to the function. Nevertheless, I think there exists a more general solution. Also the answer should not be restricted to the current use case.

Comment: I think what you want is `inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_globals`. Don't forget to `import inspect` first.

Comment: Or `sys._getframe(1)`. Although its docstring is a bit ominous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can with the inspect module, example:

test.py

```
import os
import sys
import inspect

def my_function():
    print ('Module/Function : ' + os.path.basename(__file__) + ' ' + sys._getframe().f_code.co_name +'()') 
    print ('Called from     : ' + os.path.basename(inspect.stack()[1][1]) +' ' + inspect.stack()[1][3] + '()' )
```

you can now `import test` from another module, and call the function.

test2.py

```
import test

def my_test_function():
    test.my_function()

my_test_function()
```

output:

```
Module/Function : test.py my_function()
Called from     : test.py <module>()
Module/Function : test.py my_function()
Called from     : test2.py my_test_function()
```

the first two are during `import`, the last two output lines are when you call them from `test2.py`